# SuiteBundle not availble for update

Tags: netsuite

I have a suitebundle that seems fine and updates the repository. 
when I try to install that to a customer account I get

> "This SuiteApp (bundle) currently is not available for installation or update. For access to this SuiteApp, please contact the SuiteApp owner. For NetSuite SuiteApps, contact NetSuite Customer Support."

Has anyone got any insight into the cause?